# Get Line/Col info from System.Text.Json.JsonElement

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, json-everything

I have some 3rd part code that requires a `System.Text.Json.JsonElement`, but I need to get line numbers for the `System.Text.Json.JsonElement` objects it passes back to me.

Basically I'm using [JsonSchema.Net](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything) to validate a JSON document, and I want to highlight the errors in the source json document. [JsonSchema.Net](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything) operates on `System.Text.Json.JsonElement` objects.

Is it possible to get the source line number or offset from a `System.Text.Json.JsonElement`?

It looks like the `JsonDocument` holds this information in private variables, but I can't see any way to access it.

Alternatively is there any way to manually build a `JsonDocument` (with `JsonElement` children), that way I could build it myself and keep a map of positions for each `JsonElement`?

Comment: ` I need to get line numbers for the objects it passes back to me` that's not usual.. can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve/

Comment: Basically I'm using JsonSchema.Net to validate a JSON document, and I want to highlight the errors in the source json document. JsonSchema.Net operates on System.Text.Json.JsonElement objects.

Comment: The output for JsonSchema.Net includes pointers to where the bad data is (see `instanceLocation`).  This will give you the structural details.  Is this insufficient?